# Computer disk cloning/imaging

Tags: imaging, cloning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to take an image of an hard drive partition](https://superuser.com/questions/67321/how-to-take-an-image-of-an-hard-drive-partition)

I am relatively new to the idea of disk cloning/imaging so bear with me.

I am trying to create an image of a computer that I have installed basic software on (antivirus, Word, etc) so I can install it on other machines and am trying to figure out the best and free way to accomplish this.  One of my friends suggested I try to use the "sysprep" program to create the custom image of the operating system in question - the trouble is the last time I tried using an image that was created this way it would not successfully image a computer that had different hardware (driver issues I presume).

Any suggestions?  I appreciate anyone's help in this.

Comment: You need at least to specify the platform. The answer would be very different if it was Linux, Windows or OS X.

Comment: I would like to image Windows 7 machines. I will look at the link you provided Diago - thank you.