# Make an recovery disk for Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, backup

I just bought a brand new Windows 8 PC.  How do I make a CD or DVD which will restore it to the exact conditions of when the CD was created (even if the hard drive was reformatted after the disk was created)? Thank you

**EDIT**  It is a HP Pavilion.  Don't know if that makes any difference, but I want an exact restoration with all the HP software.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take an image of a hard drive partition](http://superuser.com/questions/67321/how-to-take-an-image-of-an-hard-drive-partition) and many other questions (some of which I listed a few days back [here](http://superuser.com/questions/611349/how-do-you-usually-backup-restore-a-fresh-os-installation-instead-of-reformat#comment758570_611349)).

Comment: @user1032531 the answers in the Windows 8 upgrade Recovery Disk question aren't exactly what you want. Make sure to click the item highlighted in this picture to achieve what you want (http://i.stack.imgur.com/KOVNU.png).

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just copy everything in the C:/ drive to a HD. Then you can just copy it back on a Linux Live CD if you need to (note: if you haven't used Linux/Mac they don't have drive letter names but they just have stuff like 1TB filesystem along the left of Nautilus or Finder)

Answer (score 0):

For HP machines - They have a pre loaded software called recovery disc creator. I am not sure if the name has changed though - You can use DVD's or CD's accordingly to create a image of the partition on the discs and just in case you use them when needed, it will format the hard disk and restore it back to the original factory condition.

P.S: It does not restore the hard disk back to when the discs are created though as you've asked.